# How to disable a child item once clicked in an expandable listview in Android

Tags: android, listview

I have an expandable listview with Questions and I want each time a question is clicked or answered to have this child question disabled. Is this possible? 
thank you

This is what I have done do far

```
expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)
        {
            boolean GroupExists = linkedHashMapobject.containsKey(groupPosition);
            boolean ChildExists = linkedHashMapobject.containsValue(childPosition);

            if(GroupExists || ChildExists)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"It already exists",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }else
            {
                v.setEnabled(false);
                linkedHashMapobject.put(groupPosition,childPosition);
                CollectData(childPosition,groupPosition);
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

which does not work and disables all child elements

Comment: view.setClickable(false); will work

Answer (score 0):

you can store a list of disabled positions inside your adapter, or wherever, and check if the item is disabled, then do nothing if it is clicked.

Comment: something like Linkedhash map?

Comment: @MariaGeorgali, yes, but actually any Map

Answer (score 0):

Set 
[listener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#setOnGroupClickListener(android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener))

and get View from call, disable it by calling `view.setEnabled(false)`. I hope this helps